# Parsing SelectedValue of a ListBox to int using C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, casting, listbox

I've a listbox that uses a dictionary as a datasource.

When I want to parse the listbox's selectedvalue to a int variable, it gives me a cast exception.

The dictionary~

```
Dictionary<int, string> AssetDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

The listbox (lstAsset) datasource~

```
lstAsset.DisplayMember = "Value";
//lstAssetType.ValueMember = "Key";   //This should be lstAsset as corrected in the next line
lstAsset.ValueMember = "Key";
lstAsset.DataSource = new BindingSource(AssetDictionary, null);
```

The line where exception occurs~

```
int ush = (int)lstAsset.SelectedValue; //Specified cast is not valid.
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should the second line reference lstAsset instead of lstAssetType?

Comment: what is the value of `lstAsset.SelectedValue` while debugging?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin : You're right. My bad. How could I miss that one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide Value Member to correct control.

```
lstAsset.ValueMember = "Key";
```

and use

```
int ush = Convert.ToInt32(lstAsset.SelectedValue.ToString());
```